# Implement views::concat using C++ coroutine?

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++-coroutine, c++23

I recall reading Eric Niebler's quote somewhere: "*Coroutines* make it trivial to define your own ranges", which led me to try using coroutines to implement the well-known [`views::concat`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2542r3.html) that is not yet adopted by C++23.

Since there is currently no compiler implementing [`std::generator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/generator), I plan to use the famous [cppcoro](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro) library instead. My first attempt was to intuitively expand the lambda using the fold expression (simplified to only support ranges of `int`s):

```
#include <ranges>
#include <cppcoro/generator.hpp>

template<ranges::input_range... Rs>
auto concat(Rs&&... rngs) -> cppcoro::generator<int> 
{
  ([](auto& rng) -> cppcoro::generator<int> {
    for (auto elem : rng)
      co_yield elem;
  }(rngs), ...);
}
```

Unfortunately, that's not how coroutines work, the above just expands the lambda and [discards the returned `generator`](https://godbolt.org/z/fG8s6Yv64).

I also tried using syntactic sugar such as `co_yield rngs...;`, but this is obviously not valid syntax.

My final solution was to create a coroutine lambda that yields one element at a time (which can be simplified with [`ranges::elements_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/elements_of) in C++23). Since the return value of the coroutine is a `generator`, I can save different `generator`s by `std::array`, and then apply `views::join` to this nested range to concat its elements:

```
template<ranges::input_range... Rs>
auto concat(Rs&&... rngs) -> cppcoro::generator<int> 
{
  auto lambda = [](auto& rng) -> cppcoro::generator<int> {
    for (auto elem : rng)
      co_yield elem;
  };
  std::array nested_rng{lambda(rngs)...};
  for (auto elem : nested_rng | views::join)
    co_yield elem;
}
```

This works fine for my testcase ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rqacYKGPW)).

However, such an approach requires additional use of `std::array` to store different `generator`s and depends on `views::join`, I wonder if there is a more concise and efficient way to achieve this？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the array (or `views::join`), once you have the lambda you can fold over it:

```cpp
template<std::ranges::input_range... Rs>
auto concat(Rs&&... rs) -> std::generator<int&> 
{
    (co_yield std::ranges::elements_of(rs), ...);
}
```

I'm not sure if you can do any better until we get expansion statements.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MPn977bzf) (using the `std::generator` implementation linked to from [P2502](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2502r2.pdf)).

---

Note `generator<int&>` and not `generator<int>` because in the example I'm using `vector<int>`, whose reference type is `int&`... but `generator<int>`'s reference type is `int&&`. Attempting to directly use `elements_of(rs)` doesn't work because the reference type isn't implicitly convertible.

Comment: Great answer, didn't expect `co_yield` could really be used with fold expressions. However, I found that as long as the return type is changed to `std::generator<int&>`, we can directly [`(co_yield std::ranges::elements_of(rs), ...);`](https://godbolt.org/z/nParM5h89). Not sure why `std::generator<int>` doesn't work this way.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Ah, it has to do with reference nonsense. Cause `generator<int>` is really a range of `int&&`, and `rs` are ranges of `int&`. But if you change it to `generator<int&>`, then [it works](https://godbolt.org/z/MPn977bzf).

Comment: "*but `generator<int>`'s reference type is `int&&`*" Hum, this is *unintuitive*, given that the `generator`'s first template parameter is named `Ref`? It looks more like `generator<int&&>` to me, although I can get around this by providing a second argument to specifying the value type (e.g. `std::generator<int, int>`), so it [would work](https://godbolt.org/z/ojYWcr6Ex) too. Not sure why it was designed this way in the first place.

Comment: @康桓瑋 [P2529: `generator<T>` should have `T&&` reference_type](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2529r0.html)

Comment: Thanks for the materials, I also found the answer in the meeting minutes of [P2502](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1151#issuecomment-999813027): "*This is a performance pitfall, as you'll make a copy every time an iterator is dereferenced. This was proposed in earlier generator proposals, but no one is currently advocating for this.*" Although this still makes me a little upset..

Comment: @康桓瑋 Yeah, I was initially of the position that `generator<T>::reference` should "obviously" be `T`, but that ends up not actually being so obvious or so great.